# How to delete the User Temp folder content in a standard way, rather than manually?

Tags: windows, user, temporary-files

Instead of deleting the User Temp files manually, I want to know if there is any Windows standard way to clean the User Temp files in all of the Windows platform?

Answer (score 2):

`Start` -> `All Programs` -> `Accessories` -> `System Tools` -> `Disk Cleanup`

Among the other options, there's a `Temporary Files` checkbox in the list.

Comment: Selecting Temporary Files is not cleaning all the files in User Local Temp folder. To be specific, I want to remove the .LOG files.

Comment: As per help text I think only files with haven't been modified in over a week are removed. This is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @user2745219, welcome to SuperUser. Having 1 rep, I assume you are new to the StackExchange network. FYI, the standard way of showing appreciation is to up-vote an answer you think that was helpful. If you find an answer to fit your needs better than the other answers, you can check it as the selected answer. It is also recommended to replace your temporary username with something more personal. If you did not have the chance yet, please read the site's Tour, accessible from the Help menu above.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to manually delete it you can use some small piece of software like CCleaner to do the task for you in regular interval. There is a free version of that software is available so i would suggest go for it, if you want to maintain or organize your system in a better way then Advanced System Care or Tune Up Utilities are also good choise.

https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner

http://www.iobit.com/advancedsystemcareper.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But we are not supposed to use a 3rd party tool.

Answer (score 0):

An ugly but effective solution -without 3rd party tools- would be to add a registry item in `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Run`, which is: `del %TEMP%\*.log`
This way when the user logs in, all the .log files get deleted from the user's temp folder.

Comment: "HKCU" is for current user, so you need to edit the current user's registry of course, otherwise you add the delete command to your account. I'm sure you was aware of that, but mentioning to be sure :)